# (Reactjs) include external google maps library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I have the following non-react js code, where I want to use the Google Maps V3 geocoder:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ap  /js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4 /jquery.min.js?key=XXX"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
   ...
</script>
```

How can I create a React Component where I can access the geocoder the same way? Such as

```
export default class Map extends Component {
 myMethod(){
    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
}

render(){...}

}
```

The main problem I have is how to include the external google library into my react code.

Comment: Once you've included the google script in your page, you will get a global `google`object. That's then available everywhere (in the browser). I see you're loading jQuery, are you also loading the google maps library correctly?

Comment: yes I updated the code in my first page. Could you further explain how to include the google script in my page with React?

Comment: If the google maps API is loaded in your HTML page via a script tag, and your React code is also loaded via a script tag in your HTML page, then the `google` object will be available *everywhere*, including in code in your React components.

Comment: Where's the best place to include the google api within my react files ? because it doesn't work, if I put in in render().

Comment: I'd suggest passing the geocoder instance as a parameter when you instance your Map class. ES6 modules don't necessarily interpret undeclared variables as part of the window namespace